# Fixed Margin & Fluid Width Taking 100% of Parent

Tags: css, width, margin, fixed, fluid

How should I make this with CSS:

I would like to have 2 divs, one inside another. Parent div should take 100% of window width, child div should have fixed margins and at the same time fluid width filling 100% of the remained width of the parent. (Parent div - 2 margins of child)

It is pretty obvious how to acomplish this using javascript, but I'm wondering if there is any possibility to acomplish this using only CSS and HTML.

[Example picture](http://i44.tinypic.com/29kqfbk.jpg)

P.S. It should be valid for ie8+

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Do you want like this?

DEMO : jsfiddle.net/G5qD3

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers. The point is the answer should be _here_ even if the link dies. A link to _support_ an answer is however welcome

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #ccc;
}

.child {
width: auto;
margin: 30px;
padding: 30px;
background: #eee;
}

body {
margin : 0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">


    <div class="child">Child Container</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML
<div class="main_div">
<div class="inner_div">
    <div >sfdsd</div>
</div>
</div>

CSS
body {
margin : 0;
padding: 0;
 }
.main_div {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.inner_div {
width: 90%;
margin: 50px auto;
background: #eee;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
height: 100px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I often set the `padding` property of the outer `div` instead of setting the `margin` of the inner `div`:

```
#outer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 50px; /* this is the important thing, others are for demo purpose only*/
  height: 100px;
}

#inner {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>
```

[live demo](http://jsbin.com/ikoyul/1/)